# How far from a wooden fence should Bougainvillea be planted?

Tags: shrubs, fence

For bougainvillea to cover a wood fence how far from the fence should it be planted?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest ~ 12"-18" (see [Bougainvillea planting.AVI](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NF5E28Vhl98) - example is wall but fence should be the same). General guidance [here](http://homeguides.sfgate.com/growing-bougainvillea-up-fence-29986.html).